# Smack Presence Doesn't Work

Tags: java, smack

Actually I programming a IM service (inherited google chat) by using smack API. But when i want to print buddy list and their presences, the compile mode show all presences unavailable, but in the debug mode it shows the real availability!

My code is ...

1- create connection

```
public boolean openConnection() {
    ConnectionConfiguration connectionConfiguration = new ConnectionConfiguration("talk.google.com", 5222, "mail.google.com");
    this.connection = new XMPPConnection(connectionConfiguration);
    try {
        this.connection.connect();
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        // TODO: Send Error Information To Programmer's Email Address
    }
    if(this.connection.isConnected()) {
        this.roster = this.connection.getRoster();
        this.roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {
            public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> addresses) {}
            public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> addresses) {}
            public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> addresses) {}
            public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {}
        });
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

2- login

```
public boolean login(String jid, String password) {
    try { 
        this.connection.login(jid, password, "smack");
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        // TODO: Send Error Information To Programmer's Email Address
    }
    if(this.connection.isAuthenticated()) return true;
    return false;
}
```

3- buddy list

```
public void buddiesList() {
    Collection<RosterEntry> rosterEntries = this.roster.getEntries();
    for(RosterEntry rosterEntry: rosterEntries) {
        System.out.println(rosterEntry.username() + " === " + this.roster.getPresence(rosterEntry.getUser()));
    }
}
```

4- implementation

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    IMService imService = new IMService();
    imService.openConnection();
    imService.login("google account", "password");
    imService.buddiesList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your RosterListener doesn't do anything.  This is where you have to put code to update your roster when things like presence messages are received.

The presence you are retrieving is a snapshot in time of what the state was when it was created.  To keep the state current, you have to actually code the RosterListener.  This is clearly stated in the [Javadoc for the getPresence()](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/Roster.html#getPresence%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a Listener to your roster could be better:

https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/rosterexchange.html